# passing a parameter to query in MVC4 dataset for RDLC Report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

**Note:** I am using Microsoft Reports in MVC4

I have created a `DataSet` named DataSet1.xsd in VisualStudio in which i have added a `TableAdapter` named 'st' and in that tableadapter i have created `DataTable` named dt1. There are two methods in `dt1` `GetData()` and `Fill(@p0)`.

I have created a new `RDLC` report which is binded to that `DataSet1`
now when i try to generate the report it shows the following error

```
One or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified.
```

i dont know how to pass parameter at runtime to report

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Report(string id)
    {
        var lr = new LocalReport();
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "Report1.rdlc");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            lr.ReportPath = path;
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        var reportType = id;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;



        var deviceInfo =

        "<DeviceInfo>" +
        "  <OutputFormat>" + id + "</OutputFormat>" +
        "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
        "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
        "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
        "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
        "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
        "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
        "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;

        var renderedBytes = lr.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);


        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
        }
}
```

i have tried the following ways to add parameters but finds no success

```
var param0 = new ReportParameter("p0", "1");
rl.SetParameters(new[]{param0});
```

Comment: try to give a look at this post, it will maybe help with your issue http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7cce3c91-f876-417a-81cc-10e10dde0e40/one-or-more-parameters-required-to-run-the-report-have-not-been-specified?forum=vsreportcontrols